# MaterialUi Textfield input

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to test material-ui on my react project.

When I want to write on a `TextField` I have to click under the line of the textfield by 1cm so i can begin the writing.

[image: Exemple]

If I put the cursor in the black dot nothing happen and i can't write in the `TextField`.

But if I put the cursor ( Red Dot) I can write in the `textfield` .

Is there a way to fix this ?

edit: Found the problem in my css an HR caused this

Comment: Post your CSS code which you are overwriting.

Comment: I guess it has something to do with `inputStyle` property.

Comment: An answer is impossible unless you post the relevant HTML and CSS.

Comment: <TextField
      hintText="Hint Text"
    /><br />

I always have to select under the line

Comment: Edit your question with JS/JSX, of what style you implemented for `hintText`.